# R lubridate customise week_start by year

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, lubridate

Here is my example data, and I want to customise week_start by year in `wday` function from `lubridate` package

```
mydate <- data.frame(Date = c("13/09/2021", "13/09/2020", "13/09/2019", "13/09/2018"))
```

For instance, the start of the week will be `year %% 7`. But I got the following error when I run my code

`numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

mydate2 <- mydate %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(as.Date(as.factor(Date), format = "%d/%m/%Y")),
         years = year(Date),
         days = wday(Date, label = TRUE, week_start = years %% 7))
```

I think I need to use the `map` function from `purrr`. I have tried few times, but it didn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `map2_chr` to have a custom `week_start` for every `Date` based on `year` value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mydate %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
         years = year(Date),
         days = map2_chr(Date, years, 
                  ~as.character(wday(.x, label = TRUE, week_start = .y %% 7))))


#        Date years days
#1 2021-09-13  2021  Mon
#2 2020-09-13  2020  Sun
#3 2019-09-13  2019  Fri
#4 2018-09-13  2018  Thu
```